# Remove base class refactoring command

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resharper

Situation: Base class B where classes X, Y and Z derive from.

B is unwanted since it only provides a few properties and not general usefull implementation. I'd like to collapse all code from B into derived classes X, Y and Z.

Does a refactoring command exist for this usecase in e.g. Visual Studio (2010), Resharper (7.1/8.0/8.1) or VSCommands2010?

Answer (score 2):

I think Push members down (Resharper) is what you are looking for:

1. Open the base class `B`
2. Right click on the class name
3. Refactor...
4. Push Members Down...